# Angular Paging, numbers of button page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, paging

I do not know how to do to make it appear sufficient amount buttonów depending on items. I calculated how much should be bars but I do not know how to display them. Is powninienem use some for loop ??

```
$scope.generateButtons = function () {
        var buttons = [],
            pageCount = getPageCount(),
            buttonCount;


        console.log("page " + pageCount);

        buttonCount = pageCount > 2 ? 3 : pageCount;

        buttons.push(+buttonCount - 1);
        buttons.push(+buttonCount);
        buttons.push(+buttonCount + 1);

        return buttons;
    };
```

[All Projekt in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N8HZ6qCtsj0fF4YMULFW)

Comment: Why not to use existing Angular.UI pagination?

Comment: You could also use `ui.bootstrap` for pagination.

Comment: Because Angular.UI pagination it's not testing, and this pagination must be a backend pagination